# Download Linux native x86_64 GCC toolchain?

Tags: gcc, c, gnu

I'd like do download the GNU GCC package toolchain for Ubuntu, and not install it (`sudo apt install build-essential`) - just download. There are [toolchains for cross-building for Arm targets](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads), but I need the native `x86_64` toolchain `.tar.gz` package.

Where do I find it?

Answer (score 0):

`apt` can download the files, even if this option doesn't appear in the help menu:

```
apt download build-essential
```

Comment: I've tried it already, but it gave me `control.tar.xz`, `data.tar.xz`, etc. Not usable...